# AWS Lambda function for upload/putObject image works only on local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function which uses 'request' to get a stream of a file by URL and suppose to upload it to a bucket on s3.
It is working perfectly on my local machine using node but not inside the lambda.
After running the lambda, I have an empty file with the name I wanted.

**Stuff you should know**

- The lambda function is async
- The node version is 8.10
- In the example you see putObject, but I have also tried with upload
- Even when adding a manual sleep of 90-120 seconds to let the lambda run, the file is not uploaded
- I tried using context.succeed or callback('some result'), but it still did not work properly

**This is the relevant part of the code**

```js
module.exports.handler = async(event, context, callback) => {
  const path = 'bucketToUpload';
  const name = 'imageFileName.jpg';
  let options = {
    uri: responseUrl, // This is the url of the image
    encoding: null
  };
  let reqRes = await request(options); // Here I have the stream
  let awsPutRes = await s3.client.putObject({
    Body: reqRes.body,
    Key: name,
    Bucket: path
  }).promise();
};
```

Would really appreciate any help or directions for this issue.

Comment: Put the code in `try catch` and see what error you are getting. Check your lambda have access of `s3` bucket

Comment: Hey @Aabid , 

Sorry for not adding the code for that here but I did use try catch and I do know lambda has access since the file is create in the wanted bucket but with size 0 compared to local machine where it works and creating a file with the proper size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more tries I was able to solve the issue.

Here is part of the code:

```js
async function upload(fileStream, fileName, bucketName) {
  let params = {
    Body: fileStream,
    Key: fileName,
    Bucket: bucketName
  };
  await s3.client.putObject(params).promise();
}

module.exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
  try {
    let s3UploadParams = {
      uri: imageDownloadUrl,
      encoding: null
    };
    let imageFileStream = await request(s3UploadParams);
    await upload(imageFileStream, s3FileName, bucketName);
  } catch (err) {
    context.fail(null, 'Error trying to upload to aws' + err);
  }
}
```

Instead of using 'request' lib I am using 'request-promise-native' to get the stream from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you issue in `s3 putObject function.`

Use `s3.putObject` instead `s3.client.putObject`

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

 s3.putObject({
        Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
        Key: event.key,
        Body: buffer,
 }).promise()
```

Also this link to Upload image on s3 from URL help you : [here](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-fetch-file-and-store-in-s3/handler.js)

Comment: I have just uploaded the answer.
The s3.client is a common library I use in my project and it seems to be fine.

Thanks anyway!